# Covering Polygon with Circles of different radius

Tags: linear-programming, polygons

I have a closed polygon and I would like to fully cover it with a set of K circles of different radius such that the area covered by the circles but outside the polygon is minimal. This seems the ideal candidate for linear programming. Does anybody know a standard formulation / an algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Is your polygon convex? Is `K` a given, fixed number, or a number that you can choose? And the same question for the radii of the circles?

Comment: Polygon may not be convex, K is fixed and radii can be different

Comment: What's the exact value of `K` in your case of interest? The complexity depends strongly on `K`.

Answer (score -1):

You could have a look at [Smallest-circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) which is equivalent to your problem with `K = 1`.

In the above Wiki page it is said that a linear algorithm exists. However the algorithm described in the *loc. cit.* paper of Nimrod Megiddo is complicated.

So my feeling is that, you might be able to state your problem with linear programming, but finding the best algorithm will be far from obvious.